# Ubuntu: shell_exec : must be privileged to use -u

Tags: ubuntu, shell-exec

I need some help

```
 <?php
 echo shell_exec('(crontab -u rkevx21 -l; echo "* * * * * /path/to/command1") | crontab -u rkevx21 - 2>&1'); echo shell_exec('sudo crontab -u rkevx21 -l 2>&1'); 
 ?>
```

It gives me this result:

```
  must be privileged to use -u * * * * * /path/to/command
```

How can I resolve this. thank you.

Comment: Are you executing script via web or shell?